# How to paste text into an org table with a set number of columns?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I usually have a bulk of items separated by either spaces or new lines and I want to have them all full a table with a set number of columns.

Basically if I want the table to always have 3 columns, then this text:

```
test1 test2     test3 test4
   test5  test6 test7
```

will become:

```
|test1|test2|test3|
|test4|test5|test6|
|test7|     |     |
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your text

```
test1 test2     test3 test4
   test5  test6 test7
```

Use `C-M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`) to group the text by three, i.e.,

```
;; Type C-q C-j to get <newline>
C-M-% [ <newline>]+ → \,(if (zerop (% (1+ \#) 3)) "\n" "|")
```

then you'll get

```
test1|test2|test3
test4|test5|test6
test7|
```

Use `C-x r t` (`string-rectangle`) to prepend `|` to each line, then you'll get

```
|test1|test2|test3
|test4|test5|test6
|test7|
```

Switch to `org-mode` and press `TAB`, then you'll get

```
| test1 | test2 | test3 |
| test4 | test5 | test6 |
| test7 |       |       |
```

---

If you want an Emacs command to do the above, you can refer to the code below:

```el
(defun my-org-table-convert-region (b e)
  (interactive "*r")
  (let ((s (delete-and-extract-region b e))
        (old-point (point))
        (counter 0))
    (insert
     (replace-regexp-in-string
      (rx (1+ (in "\s\t\n")))
      (lambda (_)
        (if (zerop (% (cl-incf counter) 3))
            "\n"
          " "))
      (string-trim s)))
    (org-table-convert-region old-point (point) " +")))
```

Comment: Beautiful! but just to make it easier, I switched "|" to " " and afterwards applied org-table-create-or-convert-from-region. Is there a way to lump all what I described in my comment here in a function that I can call on a marked region?

Comment: @SFbay007 Not sure if I understand you correctly (my English is not very good), I've just added a function to automate the process.

Comment: That was exactly what I asked for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I found a small bug that I cant explain. When there are many variables (over 20) I noticed that the [first row, third column] is always empty!

Comment: @SFbay007 Not sure about the bug, though `my-org-table-convert-region` does not handle the tab character, it's probably a better idea to replace `"\s\n"` with `"\s\t\n"`, maybe your text contains the tab character?

Comment: Nope, that was not it.

Comment: Found the issue. If there was a space before the very first variable then it consider it as the second variable. Is there a way to ignore the first space/tab/newline that might come before the first variable?

Comment: I found I can use  ^[ ]* ->   to replace the first spaces, but I can't figure a way to add it to your function.

Comment: @SFbay007 Now I understand the bug, I've update the code, I use `string-trim` (from `subr-x.el`) to remove whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: Brilliant! worked perfectly.